# Export certain columns from a Matlab matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a Matlab Matrix and would like to know if there is a way to extract certain columns from this to make a new matrix.

For example, if i have a matrix of;

> data=1:20

I would like to export data from columns 1,2, 9,10 and make a new matrix file.

I would like to scale this up to a matrix of about 4,400 columns...so if there is a way to select columns at defined points (like every 8th and 9th column), then that would be super!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Aj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you also want to grab individual columns or rows similar process can be used and then concatenate the into a matrix

```
x=data(:,2) % get the 2nd column

y=data(:,8) % get the 8th 

z=[x;y] or z=[x:y] % combine them
```

If you table is standard you can predefine them in a small script

Answer (score 1):

The example you've given can be done like this:

```
x=data([1,2,9,10]);
```

You can get every 8th column like this:

```
index=8;
x=data(index:index:end);
```

If you want every 8th and 9th column and to maintain the order:

```
index1=8;
index2=9;
x=data(sort([index1:index1:end index2:index2:end]));
```